# JavaScript, window.open, clean url's and Internet Explorer 10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, window.open, clean-urls

I'm using clean url in my website (implemented through htaccess). It works beautifully.

As expected, an address like this (http://www.mysite.com/mypage/param1) means (http://www.mysite.com/mypage.php?id=param1). It's all good but...

In this page (**mypage.php**), I have a button that runs some **JavaScript**. The last instruction is:

```
window.open('otherpage.php?id=x&t=2');
```

In **Firefox** and **Chrome**, it opens the correct page:

http://www.mysite.com/otherpage.php?id=x&t=2

But **IE** (I'm using IE10 on Windows 8) tries to open something different:

http://www.mysite.com/mypage/otherpage.php?id=x&t=2 (as if **mypage** were a folder)

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and what I have to do for **IE** to open the desired page?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

After getting some answers (thank you all for promptly reply), I realized I should have been more specific. The page **mypage.php** is not in the root folder, neither is **otherpage.php**. Because of the nature of my system, I can't use absolute path, so I need a solution that works as a relative path (if at all possible).

Thank you again.

Comment: Instead of window.open('otherpage.php?id=x&t=2'); could you do window.open('/otherpage.php?id=x&t=2');

Comment: Do you have IE opened to a different URL? If so, look up relative url resolution.

Comment: Thank you Justice. Unfortunately I can't use absolute path. The JavaScript runs in many pages, in different locations, so the solution (if at all possible) should use relative path.

Answer (score 0):

You need a leading slash for urls that end in a slash (e.g. /mypage/), it should always be opening up relative to your current pathname when you do not include a leading slash

`window.open('/otherpage.php?id=x&t=2');`

Comment: Thank you Rob. But this creates a different issue. I should have been more specific. The page in question (the one I want to open) is not in the root folder. I tried this solution but it did not work as it looke for "otherpage.php" in the root folder.

Comment: That makes sense, hope you were able to find a solution to your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to the appropriate page through relative links.

```
./ = current directory
../ = one directory higher
```

So if your second page is in another directory at the same level as your current directory you can do something like this

```
./../otherdirectory/otherpage.php
```

if it's in a sub directory do something like this

```
./subdirectory/otherpage.php
```

and if it's two levels up:

```
./../../otherpage.php
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks user1883872, but this does not solve my issue, as your solution would apply to all browsers. As my problem is only in IE, I need something that would make the problem agnostic (overcome IE limitations) or act only on IE itself.

Comment: Maybe switch up your quotes from ' to "
It could be a bug in IE